# Is it possible to use Amazon SQS from Google Compute Engine virtual servers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-sqs

Is it possible to use Amazon SQS from Google Compute Engine virtual servers? And if it is, what are the potential problems of this approach? Having two different accounts (Google's and Amazon's) is, of course, one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access SQS from any machine connected to the Internet. SQS endpoint FQDN will resolve to a publicly accessible IP.

The only complication is that you will not be able to use EC2 roles for transparent permissions and key rotation. So on the Google Compute Engine side you will have to provide AWS API keys to CLI/SDK explicitly, and you're responsible for key rotation yourself.